# Linking to a webpage with a search function and auto filtering that function

Tags: 2013, search, filter, postback, search-box

In my company, there is a SharePoint site with a page with a search box on it. Underneath this box are two separate web parts, showing two separate lists.

The user is asked to enter a value into the search box and click "Go". Doing this auto-filters the two list web parts. The first list should show a single result based on the search criteria. The second list will show multiple items based on the search criteria.

I'd like to link to this page from another SharePoint site (in the same collection). Even better though, I'd like to be able to link to it in such a way that when a user clicks the link, the search criteria is auto populated and the "go" button is pressed.

I tried opening developer mode on the search page and recording the interaction which occurred when I entered the search criteria and clicked go. There was a single POST request:

```
/sites/[SP Site]/SitePages/[Page Name].aspx?ConnectionFilterString=FilterField1[LotsofText]FilterValue1[LotsofText][SearchCriteriaEntered]
```

I tried using this exact link, but it just opens the page without the search having been performed.

Is there any way I can link to the results already filtered from another page?

Screenshot of search page (anonymised):

[image]

Comment: Is the page using Search Web Parts or connected list view web parts?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott: I honestly don't know, as the page hosting the search functions isn't owned by me and I have no edit access over it.

Comment: Ope the page source and have a look at the web parts. Or post a screen shot. It is super easy to do with Search Web parts. Not so much for list views.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott: Does that screenshot help? I've anonymised it a lot, but have kept the outlines around the web part and how the search function looks.

Comment: Looks like web parts for list views. Try using Search Web parts instead. Add `k=query` to the URL.